# How to query the current URL to see if it contains a certain string

Tags: vb.net

What I want to do is take the full contents of the address bar and see if everything after the site path (i.e. everything after the question mark), contains a certain string, and if it does then return a path using the site URL and that string.

An example and some code to make things understandable:

If I'm on `www.example.com/?blah=image` I want the code to look for the string `image` (after the question mark to prevent sites with image in the name to screw things up) and if it exists return `www.example.com/images/` (with that current domain being looked up and not manually written as this will be used on mutliple sites)

Below is what I have written so far.

```
Public ReadOnly Property StorageRoot() As String
    Get
        Dim currentabsolute As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
        Dim currentdomain As String = CurrentDomain
        If currentabsolute.Contains("Media") Then
            Return System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\media\"
        ElseIf currentabsolute.Contains("Docs") Then
            Return System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\docs\"
        ElseIf currentabsolute.Contains("Image") Then
            Return System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\images\"
        End If
    End Get
End Property
```

I know `CurrentDomain` won't return anything and `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` doesn't seem to return what I am looking for so those are part of what I am hoping to get help with.

Any help will be appreciated and if you need any more clarification just ask.

Edit: Updated code

Comment: Will this code run in a page codebehind, in an HttpHanlder, or under MVC? Also, this article (http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths) may help.

Comment: Yes it runs in a codebehind and in an ihttphandler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `Request.QueryString` member. To read the value of a specific query string parameter, try something along the lines of:

```
If Request.QueryString("Media") IsNot Nothing Then
    Return currentdomain + "/media/"
ElseIf ...
```

If a query string does not contain the key in question, accessing that index will return nothing; otherwise it will return the value of that parameter. For instance, you could test to see if the string was constructed as `?Media=MyMedia` with `If Request.QueryString("Media") = "MyMedia"`.

If you want the raw query string itself, you could parse the `Request.RawUrl` member for everything after the question mark with something like:

```
Dim queryString As String = Request.RawUrl.SubString(Request.RawUrl.IndexOf("?"c) + 1)
```

Comment: Using `Request.`anything gives me the error `Request is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level`

Comment: `Request` is only available as a property of the `Page` class, otherwise you will need to inspect the `Request` property of the `HttpContext` that is available to your handler method or use `HttpContext.Current.Request`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know how it does for you:

```
Imports System.Web

...

Public ReadOnly Property StorageRoot() As String 
    Get
        Dim requestUrl As Uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
        Dim newUrl As New UriBuilder(requestUrl.Scheme, requestUrl.Host, requestUrl.Port, HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath)
        Dim currentQuery As String = requestUrl.Query 

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentQuery)
            ' What to do if there is no query string?
        Else If currentQuery.Contains("Media", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then 
            newUrl.Path = newUrl.Path + "/media/" 
        ElseIf currentQuery.Contains("Docs", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then 
            newUrl.Path = newUrl.Path + "/docs/" 
        ElseIf currentQuery.Contains("Image", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then 
            newUrl.Path = newUrl.Path + "/images/" 
        End If 

        Return newUrl.ToString()
    End Get 
End Property
```

Comment: It's not working before the point of creating the newUrl. I know this because if I manually put in the returned path it still doesn't work. What's the best way of returning the currentQuery to see if it should be working or not?